# How to Call a Custom Field in the Head Area?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to output the contents of a custom field (created through the More Field plugin) in the  area of my header.php template with:

```
<?php if ( in_category('5') ) {echo '<meta property="text" content="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_field', true) . '" />';}?>
```

...and it is currently outputting:

```
<meta property="text" content="" />
```

As you can see, it's not grabbing the value in the 'custom_field'.

Can someone please tell me how to successfully grab the value of that custom field?

P.S. I think this has something to do with the loop but i haven't yet figured out how to apply the correct syntax to make it work yet.  Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Had `get_the_ID()` returned what you want and are the custom field really named `custom_field` without any prefix or suffix?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out thanks to [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-call-a-custom-field-in-head?replies=9).

The code looks like:

```
<?php 
if (in_category('5')) 
{ 
    the_post(); 
    rewind_posts();
    echo '<meta property="text" content="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_field', true) . '" />';
} 
?>
```

Thanks for your reply PeterWong.